# JAVA positioning labels on JFRAME

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I need to draw a horizontal histogram, and i am setting up the labels of the histogram as follows,

## CODE

```
public static void drawVertical(){

 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Horizontal Histogram");
 frame.setSize(300, 300);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      


 JLabel label_01=new JLabel("0-29");  
 label_01.setAlignmentX(-290);
 label_01.setAlignmentY(290);

 JLabel label_02=new JLabel("30-39"); 
 label_02.setAlignmentX(-290);
 label_02.setAlignmentY(270);

 JLabel label_03=new JLabel("40-69"); 
 label_03.setAlignmentX(-290);
 label_03.setAlignmentY(250);

 JLabel label_04=new JLabel("70-100"); 
 label_04.setAlignmentX(-290);
 label_04.setAlignmentY(230);

 frame.add(label_01);
 frame.add(label_02)
 frame.add(label_03);
 frame.add(label_04);
 }
```

But this is the output i get :(

## OUTPUT

[image]

And this is my expected output (Edited with MS paint),

## Expected Output

[image]

Can anyone figure out whats wrong here? 
Why arent the other labels being displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that you should not use a `BorderLayout` (which the `JFrame` uses by default), but instead use a `GridLayout`. This will allow you to just add the `JLabels` to your `JFrame`. An example looks like this:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stackoverflow | Question");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // This is the important line. This will Change the layout to a GridLayout.
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    frame.add(new JLabel("0-29"));
    frame.add(new JLabel("30-39"));
    frame.add(new JLabel("40-69"));
    frame.add(new JLabel("70-100"));
    frame.setVisible(true);
});
```

Comment: There is no need to use `getContentPane()` when adding a component to the content pane of the frame. You can just add the component to the frame and the frame will add it to the content pane.